# Should I accept a std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> by const reference or by value?

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, std-pair

I've identified this as a bottleneck in my program. I know that the answer is to profile, and I've done so, but my results are inconsistent and vary with different optimization settings. Later on in the development of my program, once we've settled on which optimizations we are using, I can get a better answer, but I'm sure it also depends on the compiler in use, and maybe other factors, so I'm wondering what a good general best practice is, so I can hopefully pick the best choice now and not have to change the type signatures of a whole bunch of functions :)

Comment: Inconsistent in what way?

Comment: Assuming your analysis is correct, colour me surprised. Note that if this pair is a value in a map, it should be `std::pair<const unsigned int, unsigned int>`, just in case that's relevant.

Comment: If it's a 64-bit machine with a 32-bit `int`, take it by value. If it's a bigger `int`, measure and ensure that you are generating code with the right optimization levels and architecture specifications. For example, `O3` and `march=native`, assuming the build and target machines are the same.

Comment: BTW, [Boost.CallTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm) gives you the flexibility to change your mind later on, without having to change the type signatures of a whole bunch of functions.

Comment: In general, you should prefer to pass relatively small objects with cheap copy constructors (e.g. - int, std::pair<int, int>) by value rather than const reference.  This can allow the compiler to better optimize that function.  The one provisio to this recommendation is if the function has a good chance of being inlined, then const reference may be better as the compiler can optimize away any/all argument passing overhead, which may not be possible if you pass by value with a non-POD copy constructor or you alter the value in the function.

Comment: @jschultz410 Thanks! A lot of these functions are quite small so it is pretty likely that they will be inlined.